# Passing ID from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am developing a job portal website, and I am looking to pass the current job ID over to the "job applications" controller #new method, but I am having issues being able to do so.

So when a user clicks the "Job_applications#new", It gets the current page job_id.

Models

```
Class Job 
  has_many :job_applications
end

Class JobApplication
  belongs_to :job
end
```

In my Job_Applications Controller

```
def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    *Additional save & Redirect methods*
end
```

In my View I have the following code

```
<%= link_to "Apply Now",new_job_application_path(:id => @job.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I know I am doing something stupid here, Ideally, I would like to pass the job id without it being in the URL

Example

```
domain.com/job_application/new
```

However this method shows this

```
domain.com/job_application/new?id=3
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
new_job_application_path(id: @job.id)
```

You should be able to retrieve it like you are doing:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, When I try to use this, I get the error "Couldn't find Job with 'id'= "

Comment: What does the controller look like for that view?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appear to have solved the problem by moving the param[:id] line into the "new" method,

Answer (score 0):

if you want your params to not appear in the url, u got to use a `POST` request.

However, note that using a post request for a 'new' action is not 'Restful', which is what Rails is based on, but its not impossible.

Read more on 'Restful routes' [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).